# Can NodeJS function app.listen() Choose site IP?

Tags: node.js, server, socketserver

I have a Windows Server host with two network cards:
192.168.1.205 and 192.168.1.206;
192.168.1.205 Running IIS and using 80 port and 443 port which is working fine,
I expect 192.168.1.206 used as node js webSocketServer,
And only use 192.168.1.206 network card,
But whenever I execute app.listen(), it takes up two network cards IP
Code:

```
 var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, resolveURL('xxxxx.pem'))),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, resolveURL('xxxxx.pem')))};  
 var app = server.createServer(options, serverHandler);

 function runServer() {
     app = app.listen(443, '0.0.0.0', function(error) {
        var addr = app.address();
  }
 }
```

I try to Change IP like this

```
 function runServer() {
     app = app.listen(443, '192.168.1.206', function(error) {
        var addr = app.address();
  }
 }
```

But did not help,
Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean it takes up two addresses? What's the error, more precisely (error message from node). In the second case, can it be reached from the `.205` address as well?

Comment: This means that after I compile nodeJS, 443port in IIS (192.168.11.205) can not be used,
So I think he took away my two IP addresses,
In the second case, have same problem